# Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service"

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install Devstack but it stopping in the middle

Currently trying to install openstack, but the long process of individual installation, so am using devstack, however i already install OSM release 5. I just need a vim to put the images. Anyway I am installing openstack using devstack. But it's stopping in the middle . This was the error i am getting,

```
See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
chmod 644 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_uwsgi.so
+lib/apache:install_apache_uwsgi:102       popd
~/devstack
+lib/apache:install_apache_uwsgi:104       sudo rm -rf /tmp/tmp.EgMQRfNaCS
+lib/apache:install_apache_uwsgi:106       is_ubuntu
+functions-common:is_ubuntu:466            [[ -z deb ]]
+functions-common:is_ubuntu:469            '[' deb = deb ']'
+lib/apache:install_apache_uwsgi:108       sudo a2enmod proxy
Module proxy already enabled
+lib/apache:install_apache_uwsgi:109       sudo a2enmod proxy_uwsgi
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_uwsgi:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_uwsgi already enabled
+lib/apache:install_apache_uwsgi:115       restart_apache_server
+lib/apache:restart_apache_server:231      restart_service apache2
+functions-common:restart_service:2393     '[' -x /bin/systemctl ']'
+functions-common:restart_service:2394     sudo /bin/systemctl restart apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
+functions-common:restart_service:1        exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:521                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:531                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:417               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:538                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:539                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:541                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:542                  generate-subunit 1559639730 82 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:544                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:547                  /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2019-06-04-091653.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:556                  exit 1
)
```

Upon running apache restart, its gives this.

```py
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for deta
```

So i tried to kill all pids then it's ok for once, after that it comes back up

```py
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ti 2019-06-04 12:48:10 EEST; 3min 47s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2339 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2314 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since ti 2019-06-04 12:52:15 EEST; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10597 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10555 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then after some seconds the error comes back. H

```py
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ti 2019-06-04 12:53:29 EEST; 10s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 13707 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 13680 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
stack@bozz-feedz:/etc/apache2$ 
$)
```

Except i kill the pids again. I don't understand why this is happening.

I expect the devstack to install completely. It's just tiring

Comment: What DevStack version are you using? Are you running any other web server in your current host? what's the output for `netstat -l`?

Comment: the output is very long

Comment: Can you use a pastebin service like [link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/)? I would like to see the output. Please also remove any real public IP, please replace it with a fake IP.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hNVpntC5Sv/

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hNVpntC5Sv/

Comment: That's the output

Comment: I need also the following outputs `ps aux`. `cat  /var/log/apache2/error.log` `sudo lxd status`  `lxc list`

Comment: px aux.  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3kDm83JR6x/    , No error.log file    lxd status https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/wkwdcjC2sv/    lxc list https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6ThFBcbdRc/

Comment: What are all these for, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall apache2.
It worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get reinstall apache2
```